# NFS export filesystem

Tags: nfs

I have several internal disk mounted on media folder like following.

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /media/disk1
mount /dev/sde1 /media/disk2
mount /dev/sdf1 /media/disk3
```

Now I am trying to export /media via nfs.

```
/media 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,all_squash,nohide,crossmnt)
```

On the client(Mac) side I am mounting NFS like following

```
 mount -t nfs -o rw,sync <ip_of_server>:/media nfsmedia
```

It does mount without any error. It shows the 3 directories as expected, however there is no content in nfsmedia/disk1, nfsmedia/disk2, nfsmedia/disk3 directories.

If I export each disk separately and mount separately on client side, it works.

```
/media/disk1 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,all_squash,nohide,crossmnt)
/media/disk2 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,all_squash,nohide,crossmnt)
```

On client side mount

```
mount -t nfs -o rw,sync <ip_of_server>:/media/disk1 nfsmedia
```

This does mount disk1 as expected, will all the contents. However it is not optimal to mount several mountpoints across multiple computers.

Is there a way to export them as a single directory?

Comment: speaking of stackexchange, does [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/how-to-properly-export-and-import-nfs-shares-that-have-subdirectories-as-mount-p) answer the question?

Comment: I did come across that solution. But it didn't work.

Comment: This seems to be working. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount Bind all locally mounted disks to new set of folders and export that single folder via NFS.